# SequelizeConnectionError when Upgrade Node.js (4x to 7x)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I upgrade my node.js version from "node-v4.8.3-win-x64" to "node-v7.10.1-win-x64". But I had SequelizeConnectionError:

```
SequelizeConnectionError: password authentication failed for user “user”
{
    "name":"error",
    "length":122,
    "severity":"FATAL",
    "code":"28000",
    "file":".\\src\\backend\\libpq\\auth.c",
    "line":"273",
    "routine":"auth_failed"
}
```

This is my sequelize connection:

```
 var sequelize = new Sequelize(
     "dbname", "user", "password",
     {
         dialect: "postgres",
         host: "localhost",
         port: "5432"
     }
 );
```

Sequelize Version: ~3.19.3

Do I have to make some change to work in this new version of node?

PS: I already tried to replace user, pass and dbname to one connection url. But shows the same error

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be the "pg" version. Everything works when I updated from "~4.4.4" to "~4.5.6".